# Calculating means in R, via case/row frommultiple variables; count and exclude NA values

Tags: r, average, missing-data

I'm trying to calculate participant average scores on the following scheme:
1. Take a series of values from multiple variables (test items),
2. Calculate an average score only for items answered Yes or No,
3. Omitting NA values from affecting the mean yet counting frequency and getting coordinates for all NA values, 
4. Storing that newfound mean value in a new variable.

I need to do this with binary questions (1 = Yes, 0 = No, -99 = Missing / NA), such as below:

`id var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
1   1   0   0   0   0
2   1   1   0   1   1
3   1   0   0   1   0
4   1   0   0   1   0
5   1   0   0   0   0
6   1   1   0   0   1
7   1   1   0   0   1
8   1   1   0   0   0
9   1   0   1   0   1
10  1   0   0   -99 1
11  1   1   0   1   0
12  1   0   0   1   0
13  1   0   0   -99 0
14  1   -99 0   1   1
15  1   0   0   1   0
16  1   0   0   0   1
17  1   0   0   1   0
18  1   0   -99 0   1
19  1   0   0   1   0
20  1   0   0   1   1
21  1   0   0   1   0
22  1   0   0   1   1
23  1   0   0   1   0
24  1   0   0   0   1
25  1   0   0   0   0
26  1   0   0   1   0
27  1   0   0   0   0
28  1   1   0   1   1`

And with Likert scale questions (0 = Strongly Disagree / 6 = Strongly Disagree, -99 Missing / NA).

`var10 var11   var12   var13   var14
1   1   1   1   0
4   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   0
4   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
-99 1   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   1
1   4   2   2   0
4   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1`

Any ideas of how to go about this? I'm sure it can be done by selecting individual columns or by indicating a range of columns from which to draw data. However, I'm inexperienced in writing such a complex, multi-stepped function in R so I'm hoping to get a veteran's advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some example data with the variables you're trying to calculate from?

Comment: This will be easier if you provide a sample data set and then show the desired output.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. Some example data has been provided above.